# How to create or update mtime of a directory by using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to create a directory and if already the directory exists, update the `mtime` of it.

This is what I wrote:

```
Dir.exist?(dir) ? FileUtils.touch(dir) : FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir)
```

Is there better way to enable it?

Comment: Isn't `FileUtils.touch(dir)` sufficient? [FileUtils::touch](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-touch): "Updates modification time (mtime) and access time (atime) of file(s) in list. Files are created if they don’t exist."

Comment: The docs give this example for `mkdir_p`: `FileUtils.mkdir_p '/usr/local/lib/ruby'`, which will create parents as required. I don't think you can do that with `touch`, but (after testing) `touch` seems to work fine for making a single directory. I've not used `touch` before so don't really know about creating parents in a single step.

Comment: Docs for touch say it only affects mtime and atime, not ctime. Also it would only create a regular file, not a dir.

Comment: @start, ah, yes, if was a file I created. :-) If `touch` created dirs, how would it know if `touch 'cat'` meant I wanted a file or a dir?

Comment: For `mtime`, it is not necessary to use `touch` since you do not need to create the file/directory. It is enough to use [`File.utime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/File.html#method-c-utime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctime` cannot be updated, since it is *creation* time(*). See [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2010-08/msg00010.html) for what POSIX says about it. If you really, *really* want to set the `ctime`, move the original directory out of the way, make a new one (this step sets `ctime`), move all the original contents to the new one, delete the old one.

Your code should be correct for updating `mtime` (*modification* time), though.

---

(*) Or rather, depending on your OS and filesystem, it can, if you hack at it, but you really, *really* shouldn't.

Comment: oh, sorry. I mixed up `mtime` and `ctime`. (I thought `ctime` is 'changed time'.)